# RelayJS infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm attempting to make a infinite scroll pagination in my React-Relay frontend, but without a success.

At this moment, I have this React component ...

```
class List extends Component {
  state = { loading: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      if (!this.state.loading
              && (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY)
              >= document.body.offsetHeight) {

        this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
          this.props.relay.setVariables({
            count: this.props.relay.variables.count + 5
          }, (readyState) => {
            if (readyState.done) {
              this.setState({ loading: false });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.viewer.products.edges.map(function(product, i) {
          return (<Item key={i} product={product.node} />);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

... wrapped in Relay container

```
export default Relay.createContainer(List, {
  initialVariables: {
    count: 5
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        products(first: $count) {
          total
          edges {
            node {
              ${Item.getFragment('product')}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  }
});
```

The logic behind this seems quite easy. If you reach a certain `scrollY` position, set to `count` variable a new inceremented value, which extends your list of Edges.

But this concept will lead to a situation, where in the beginning I query the database for first 5 records, but lately while I keep scrolling a will query for N+5 records. In the end I will query the database for a whole table (thousands of records)! Which is quite unacceptable.

So I'm trying to implement a `cursors`, but I don't know how to just fetch data from a connection and extend the result. This approach returns me a *"paginated"* list.

---

Also, the above code gives me this error, when I scroll down

> resolveImmediate.js?39d8:27 Uncaught Invariant Violation: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 19, pending 18)

I will be very thankful for any help or example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

About my concern of fetching N+5 records over and over again with each scroll, it seems that Relay is quite intelligent, because it automatically "*paginate*" my connection by querying `cursor` and managing the `after` arg in my connection.

And with little help from `graphql-sequelize` on my backend, it simply turns into this query

```
SELECT ... FROM product ORDER BY product.id ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Which actually solves my first problem about the performance. :)

So my `Relay.QL` query has underhood transpiled into this

```
query ListPage_ViewerRelayQL($id_0:ID!) {
  node(id:$id_0) {
    ...F1
  }
}
fragment F0 on Product {
  id,
  title,
  price
}
fragment F1 on Viewer {
  _products4tSFq4:products(after:"YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uJDUkNA==",first:5) {
    edges {
      cursor,
      node {
        id,
        ...F0
      }
    },
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  },
  id
}
```

and when I ran this query on my GraphQL backend, it returned me empty result

```
{
  "data": {
    "node": null
  }
}
```

Then I immediately realized where is the problem and why my Relay crashes down.

The problem is with **refetching the viewer**. I did not properly implemented `nodeDefinitions` and when the viewer `ID` hit `idFetcher` and `typeResolver`, it failed and returned a `null`. After that on the client side, Relay was unable to finish the refetching of my connection and crashed down!

After small repairment and **fixes on the Backend-side**, my infinite scroll works like a charm! :)

Comment: didnt get how you turned the issue of N+5 that could tend to infinite to normal a "normal" pagination with fixed amount of data that would concatenate every round which is more efficient.